# Mocked object returning null

Tags: java, mockito

I am mocking an object like this :

```
    @InjectMocks
    private AuroraRepoImpl auroraRepo;

    @Mock
    private Connector4AuroraDB connector4AuroraDB;
```

`AuroraRepoImpl` is the class and `connector4AuroraDB` is the object I need to mock.
But when the call goes to the `connector4AuroraDB`, instead of mocked it is returning `null`.

This is how it is being used :

```
Connection connection = connector4AuroraDB.openConnection();
```

It is throwing `NullPointerException`.
Any idea how to mock this?

Comment: Have you used @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)?

Comment: are you calling `MockitoAnnotations.injectMocks(this)` in your setUp method?

Comment: Are you initialising your mocks? Either by using `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` or `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)` ?

Comment: I am using MockitoAnnotations.injectMocks(this) in @before method

Comment: "It is throwing null pointer exception" at which point in the code is it throwing NPE?

Comment: Connection connection = connector4AuroraDB.openConnection();
In this line on debug it shows that connector4AuroraDB is null

Comment: Please provide the injection point in AuroraRepoImpl.

Comment: I used @InjectMocks on the class as mentioned in question. Do I need to provide in any other way as well?

Comment: How is the dependency injected? By constructor?

Comment: Nope I havent add anything to inject mock. I guess that part is done by @InjectMock annotation

Comment: Do you know what dependency injection is? Mockito is trying to inject the dependency Connector4AuroraDB into AuroraRepoImpl.
Do the AuroraRepoImpl have a constructor which takes a Connector4AuroraDB object as parameter?

Comment: I know dependeny injection.
Connector4AuroraDB is not used in constructor, but the value is @Autowired and is used like this:
Connection connection = connector4AuroraDB.openConnection();

Comment: @KumarHarsh Did you solve it? Please have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments you tell that `Connector4AuroraDB` is autowired by Spring(`@Autowired`).
It seems to me that you are using field injections, which makes it difficult to do stub dependencies.

I assume you have something like:

```
public class AuroraRepoImpl {
  @Autowired private Connector4AuroraDB connector4AuroraDB;
}
```

For this to work you need a Spring context setup, so spring can look into the bean registry to find the dependency.

Your example is a simple unit test running with `MockitoJUnitRunner`.
You should change your implementation to use injection by constructor, this way Mockito can inject the dependency:

```
public class AuroraRepoImpl {
  private final Connector4AuroraDB connector;

  @Autowired
  public AuroraRepoImpl(final Connector4AuroraDB connector) {
    this.connector = connector;
  }
}
```

If you use a new Spring version you can even omit the `@Autowired` annotation if the class only has one constructor.